# How to calculate seconds in php

Tags: php, datetime, time, format

I have this code:

```
    $hours = floor($differenceInHours);
    $minutes = ($differenceInHours-$hours)*60;
    $seconds = ':00';
    $total=$hours . ":" . $minutes .':' . $seconds;
    echo $total;
```

I want to know on how to calculate the seconds. Any formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the second parameter of the [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function to format a number of seconds into a formatted time notation. As soon as the number of hours is larger than 24, it considers that to be 1 day, so you'll have to take that into account by treating the hours separately.

```
echo floor($differenceInHours) . ':' . date('i:s', ($differenceInHours - floor($differenceInHours)) * 3600);
```

If you do not want to treat the hours separately, you can use:

```
echo date('d H:i:s', $differenceInHours * 3600);
```

(Of course, when it reaches 31 days, it considers it a month, et cetera...)

Comment: $t1  = strtotime($start_time);
  $t2 = strtotime($end_time);
  $differenceInSeconds = $t2 - $t1;
  $differenceInHours = $differenceInSeconds / 3600;
  
   if($differenceInHours<0) {
     $differenceInHours += 24; 
   }
And the problem is i just dont get the $seconds. So i'll do $hours*3600?

Comment: If you want to change the question, please edit it or start a new one.

If you start out with the times in string format, you may get what you need from [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php). See the example on that page for calculating and formatting the difference between two timestamps.

Comment: sorry for that. check this i think this one is well explained. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18117044/how-to-calculate-the-time-consumed-from-start-time-to-end-time-in-php