# How to calculate the time consumed from start time to end time in php

Tags: php, datetime, time, format

I want to get the perfect time consumed or the total time from start time to end time:
 My code:

```
   $start_time =  $this->input->post('start_time');
   $end_time =  $this->input->post('end_time');


   $t1  = strtotime($start_time);
   $t2 = strtotime($end_time);
   $differenceInSeconds = $t2 - $t1;
   $differenceInHours = $differenceInSeconds / 3600;

   if($differenceInHours<0) {
     $differenceInHours += 24; 
    }
```

In the code above if `$start_time` = `11:00:00 PM` and `$end_date =11:30:00` it gives me the output of `0.5` instead of `30minutes`. Is there any appropriate way to do it like that? 
 
So if the:

```
  $start_time  = '01:00:00 PM';
  $end_time = '01:25:00 PM';

  $total = '25:00'; // 25 minutes
```

or:

```
  $start_time  = '11:00:00 PM';
  $end_time = '11:00:25 PM';

  $total = '00:00:25'; // 25seconds
```

Regards!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) function

```
<?php
echo date_create('03:00:00 PM')->diff(date_create('03:25:00 PM'))->format('%H:%i:%s');
?>
```

Output

---

```
00:25:00
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php):

```
echo date_create('01:00:00 PM')->diff(date_create('01:25:00 PM'))->format('%H:%i:%s');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check everything using if and else statement.
I think this one help.

```
 $start_time =  "11:00:00";
 $end_time =  "12:30:00";


  $t1  = strtotime($start_time);
  $t2 = strtotime($end_time);
  $difference = $t2 - $t1;


  if($difference / 3600 > 0){
     $hour = $difference / 3600;
     $hour = (int)$hour;

     $difference = $difference - ($hour * 3600);

  }else{
     $hour = "00";
  }

  if($difference / 60 > 0){
       $min = $difference / 60;

       $difference = $difference - ($min * 60);

  }else{
       $min = "00";
  }
  function checkString($str){
        if(strlen($str)==1){
        return "0".$str;
    }
    return $str;
  }
  print_r(checkString($hour).":".checkString($min).":".checkString($difference));
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php
$start_time = strtotime('09:00:59');
$end_time = strtotime('09:01:00');
$diff = $end_time - $start_time;
echo 'Time 1: '.date('H:i:s', $start_time).'<br>';
echo 'Time 2: '.date('H:i:s', $end_time).'<br>';

if($diff){
    echo 'Diff: '.date('H:i:s', $diff);
}else{
    echo 'No Diff.';
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.  How is this answer different from earlier answers?  Did you just want to fix an error in subtraction found in an earlier answer?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You can use [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) for time calculation. Here is an example:

```
$start_time = strtotime('09:00:59');
$end_time = strtotime('09:01:00');
$diff = $start_time - $end_time;
echo 'Time 1: '.date('H:i:s', $start_time).'<br>';
echo 'Time 2: '.date('H:i:s', $end_time).'<br>';

if($diff){
    echo 'Diff: '.date('H:i:s', $diff);
}else{
    echo 'No Diff.';
}
```

Output:

```
Time 1: 09:00:59
Time 2: 09:01:00
Diff: 00:00:01
```

Comment: Subtracting the end_time from the start_time does not return `00:00:01` https://3v4l.org/CuTZG